# The address of struct PEB_LDR_DATA

Tags: windows, process, kernel32

Is there a `struct PEB_LDR_DATA` in the PEB of every process? What is the offset address of this struct in PEB? How can I find the list of loaded modules(such as `kernel32.dll`) from the base address of this struct?

Thanks!

Comment: http://qingyunoracle.blogspot.sk/2013/03/peb-and-pebldrdata-structure.html

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user2120666, I finally discovered how to locate `kernel32.dll` in `struct PEB_LDR_DATA`.

It has to be noticed that in WINDOWS7, the first node in `InInitializationOrderModuleList` is `kernelbase.dll` rather than `ntdll.dll`. The offset address has to be modified respectively.